# SQL Server Query returns results, but does not save it to Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am having problems with pyodbc - when I am running a query with multiple commands, I can fetch the results, but the changes are not saved at the table in the database.

This is my init routine of class:

```
class OJISQL():
def __init__(self):
    global engine
    global connection
    global params
    connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=********,1433;Database=***;UID=****;PWD=****;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')"
    self.connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

This is my function/SQL-Code:

```
       combined_code = f"""

            SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @AffectedRows TABLE (
        Operation NVARCHAR(10),
        [WFKKEY] INT,
        [change] DATETIME,
        [VIN] NVARCHAR(17),
        [ANNDT] DATETIME,
        [ENDDT] DATETIME,
        [RG] INT,
        [DATAGRP] BIT
    );

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] ([WFKKEY], [change], [ANNDT], [ENDDT], [RG], [DATAGRP], [VIN])
    OUTPUT 'Inserted', inserted.[WFKKEY], inserted.[change], inserted.[ANNDT],  inserted.[ENDDT], inserted.[RG], inserted.[DATAGRP], inserted.[VIN]
    INTO @AffectedRows (Operation, [WFKKEY], [change], [ANNDT], [ENDDT], [RG], [DATAGRP], [VIN])
    SELECT s.[WFKKEY], s.[change], s.[ANNDT], s.[ENDDT], s.[RG], s.[DATAGRP], s.[VIN]
    FROM (
        VALUES
            {','.join([str(i) for i in list(upldf.to_records(index=False))])}
             ) AS s ([WFKKEY], [change],  [ANNDT],  [ENDDT],  [RG], [VIN], [DATAGRP])
    WHERE not EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] t
        WHERE t.[WFKKEY] = s.[WFKKEY]
            AND t.[ANNDT] = s.[ANNDT]
            AND t.[ENDDT] = s.[ENDDT]
            AND t.[DATAGRP] = s.[DATAGRP]
            AND t.[VIN] = s.[VIN]
    );

    UPDATE h
    SET
        h.[lastchange] = a.[change]
    FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] h
    JOIN @AffectedRows a ON h.[WFKKEY] = a.[WFKKEY];

    -- Then, insert new rows
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] ([WFKKEY], [lastchange], [ANNDT], [ENDDT], [RG], [DATAGRP], [VIN], [isORDERSPECIFIED])
    SELECT
        [WFKKEY], [change], [ANNDT],  [ENDDT],  [RG], [DATAGRP], [VIN], 1 AS isORDERSPECIFIED
    FROM @AffectedRows
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD] h JOIN @AffectedRows aff
        ON h.[WFKKEY] = aff.[WFKKEY]
            AND h.[ANNDT] = aff.[ANNDT]
            AND h.[ENDDT] = aff.[ENDDT]
            AND h.[DATAGRP] = aff.[DATAGRP]
            AND h.[VIN] = aff.[VIN]
    );

    SELECT [APPKEY]
  ,[WFKKEY]
  ,[ORDERKEY]
  ,[SUBKEY]
  ,[VIN]
  ,[DATAGRP]
  ,[RG]
  ,[lastchange]
  ,[LOCKJCLSTART]
  ,[LOCKJCLEND]
  ,[brokeninmultiple]
  ,[CLOCKINGREF]
  ,[isORDERSPECIFIED]
  ,[ANNDT]
  ,[ENDDT]
    FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_HEAD]
    WHERE [ANNDT] <= '{formatted_date_str}T23:59:00.000' AND [ENDDT] >= '{formatted_date_str}T00:00:00.000';
    """

    try:
        rows = self.cursor.execute(combined_code).fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame((tuple(t) for t in rows))
        df.columns = [column[0] for column in self.cursor.description]
        if df.empty:
            print("APPSCHED_HEAD DF IS EMPTY!")
        else:
            upsert_redis("APPSCHED_HEAD",daystr,df)
            return df
    except Exception as e:
        # If an exception occurred, handle the error
        print("Error occurred during insert:",e)
```

I do not get any errors, and a `df` is returned. After that, when I query with `SSMS`, there are no results in the table.

Comment: So the data frame contains the data, but the sql table does not? Or is the dataframe empty as well?

Comment: you use this code to temporarily debug :     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';  
GO       from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples

Comment: @Xedni dataframe has the data, but it is not stored in db table - it feels  like a rollback transaction, after the last command, everything is rolled back

Comment: `autocommit=true`

Comment: @Charlieface: please give you answer that I can check it as solution